How can I upload Multiple Images in a One Post
I am trying to create a mock social media app and everything works fine for now. However, I wonder if I can manage to upload up to 5 images for one post and also fetching and rendering them. I just want to get your coding suggestions about this. Here are some codes:
package CIC.social_media_api.controller;

import CIC.social_media_api.entity.PostImage;
import CIC.social_media_api.service.PostImageService;
import CIC.social_media_api.service.PostService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/post-images")
public class PostImageController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostImageController.class);

    private final PostImageService postImageService;
    private final PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    public PostImageController(PostImageService postImageService, PostService postService) {
        this.postImageService = postImageService;
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<PostImage>> getAllPostImages() {
        try {
            List<PostImage> postImages = postImageService.getAllPostImages();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(postImages);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error retrieving all post images: ", e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPostImageById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            PostImage postImage = postImageService.getPostImageById(id);
            if (postImage == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, postImage.getType());

            return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(postImage.getData());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error retrieving post image with ID {}: ", id, e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/post/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PostImage>> getImagesByPostId(@PathVariable Long postId) {
        try {
            List<PostImage> postImages = postImageService.findImagesByPostId(postId);
            if (postImages.isEmpty()) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(postImages);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(postImages);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error retrieving images for post ID {}: ", postId, e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("postId") Long postId) {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Empty file provided for upload.");
        }

        try {
            // Check if the post exists
            if (postService.findPostById(postId) == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Post not found with ID: " + postId);
            }

            PostImage postImage = postImageService.storeImage(file, postId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Image uploaded successfully: " + postImage.getId());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error uploading image for post ID {}: ", postId, e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error uploading image: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid argument error while uploading image for post ID {}: ", postId, e);
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deletePostImage(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            boolean deleted = postImageService.deletePostImageById(id);
            if (deleted) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok("Image deleted successfully");
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Image not found");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error deleting post image with ID {}: ", id, e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error deleting image: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

package CIC.social_media_api.controller;

import CIC.social_media_api.entity.Post;
import CIC.social_media_api.entity.PostImage;
import CIC.social_media_api.entity.User;
import CIC.social_media_api.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import CIC.social_media_api.service.PostService;
import CIC.social_media_api.service.PostImageService;
import CIC.social_media_api.service.UserService;
import CIC.social_media_api.response.PostResponse;// Import the PostResponse class
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/posts")
public class PostController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostController.class);

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    private PostImageService postImageService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<PostResponse>> getAllPosts() {
        try {
            List<Post> posts = postService.findAllPosts();
            List<PostResponse> postResponses = posts.stream().map(this::convertToPostResponse).toList();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(postResponses);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error retrieving all posts: ", e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PostResponse> getPostById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            Post post = postService.findPostById(id);
            return post != null ? ResponseEntity.ok(convertToPostResponse(post)) : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error retrieving post with ID {}: ", id, e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<PostResponse> createPost(@RequestParam(value = "description", required = false) String description,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
                                                   Authentication authentication) {
        try {
            Optional<User> optionalUser = userService.findByUserName(authentication.getName());

            if (!optionalUser.isPresent()) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
            }

            User user = optionalUser.get();
            Post post = new Post();
            post.setUser(user);
            post.setDescription(description);
            post.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());

            // Save the post first to generate the ID
            Post createdPost = postService.createPost(post);

            // If there's an image, save it and associate it with the post
            if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    PostImage postImage = new PostImage();
                    postImage.setName(file.getOriginalFilename());
                    postImage.setType(file.getContentType());
                    postImage.setData(file.getBytes());
                    postImage.setPost(createdPost); // Associate with the saved post
                    postImageService.createPostImage(postImage);

                    // Update the post with the new image
                    createdPost.getPostImages().add(postImage);
                    postService.updatePost(createdPost);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error storing image for post ID {}: ", createdPost.getId(), e);
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    logger.error("Invalid argument error while storing image for post ID {}: ", createdPost.getId(), e);
                    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
                }
            }

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(convertToPostResponse(createdPost));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error creating post: ", e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deletePost(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            postService.deletePost(id);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }


    @PostMapping("/{postId}/images")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadPostImage(@PathVariable Long postId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
            }

            postImageService.storeImage(file, postId);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error uploading image for post with ID {}: ", postId, e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid argument error while uploading image for post ID {}: ", postId, e);
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
    }

    private PostResponse convertToPostResponse(Post post) {
        PostResponse postResponse = new PostResponse();
        postResponse.setId(post.getId());
        postResponse.setDescription(post.getDescription());
        postResponse.setCreatedAt(post.getCreatedAt());
        postResponse.setUserId(post.getUser().getId());
        postResponse.setUserName(post.getUser().getUserName());
        postResponse.setPostImages(post.getPostImages().stream()
                .map(img -> new PostResponse.PostImageResponse(img.getName(), img.getType(), img.getData()))
                .toList());
        postResponse.setLikeCount(post.getLikes().size()); // Adjust this if you have a separate like count service
        postResponse.setDislikeCount(post.getDislikes()); // Adjust this if you have a separate dislike count service
        return postResponse;
    }
}

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import {jwtDecode} from 'jwt-decode'; // Correct import statement for jwt-decode

const PostForm = ({ onPostCreated, onCancel }) => {
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(''); // State to manage error messages

    const handlePost = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior

        const token = Cookies.get('token');
        if (!token) {
            setError('Token not found. Please log in.');
            return; // Handle error or redirect to login
        }

        try {
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token); // Decode the JWT token
            console.log('Decoded token:', decodedToken); // Log decoded token for verification

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('description', description);
            if (file) {
                formData.append('file', file); // Append file directly, as binary
            }

            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/posts', formData, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, // Use the token directly for authorization
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' // Ensure correct content type
                }
            });

            console.log('Post created:', response.data); // Log the response data
            alert('Post created successfully!');

            // Clear form inputs after successful creation
            setDescription('');
            setFile(null);
            setError('');

            // Notify parent component to refresh the feed with new post data
            if (onPostCreated) {
                onPostCreated(response.data);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating post:', error);
            // Extract and display error message if available
            const errorMessage = error.response?.data?.message || 'Failed to create post. Please try again later.';
            setError(errorMessage); // Update error message
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="post-form-container">
            <h2>Create Post</h2>
            {error && <div style={{ color: 'red', marginBottom: '10px' }}>{error}</div>} {/* Display error messages */}
            <form onSubmit={handlePost}>
                <textarea
                    placeholder="Description"
                    value={description}
                    onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100px', marginBottom: '10px', padding: '10px' }}
                />
                <input
                    type="file"
                    onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                    style={{ marginBottom: '10px' }}
                />
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="submit-button"
                    >
                        Post
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={onCancel}
                        className="cancel-button"
                    >
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PostForm;


I tryed using MultipartFile[] to save multiple files but it did not save into the database.

Did you try your API with Postman?

Hi, you've provided a lot of code and vague question. Remove the unnecessary code, provide only the method (backend) you use to upload multiple files and explain what does not work.

First of all, please provide only the required methods instead of the whole code, and you can create a controller using MultipartHttpServletRequest to handle multiple files
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadImages(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    List<String> uploadedFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        List<MultipartFile> files = request.getFiles("files");

        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                String originalFilename = file.getOriginalFilename();
                String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(originalFilename);
                String newFilename = System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + fileExtension;

                File destinationFile = new File(UPLOAD_DIR + newFilename);
                file.transferTo(destinationFile);

                uploadedFiles.add(newFilename);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(uploadedFiles, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

and use           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
in react to post this
